# UIViewController removeFromSuperview error

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` then when I longpress to `self.view` it will push a popup (`MenuViewController`). But when I try to remove popup by `removeFromSuperview` it still appears

You can see more detail of my problem with this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVVgmeJEnnY

ViewController.m

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () {
    MenuViewController *menu;
}
....
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ....
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(albumButtonPressed : ) name:@"albumButtonPressed" object:nil];
    ....
}

....

-(void)albumButtonPressed : (NSNotification*) notification {
    UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photoPicker.delegate = self;
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:photoPicker animated:YES];
}

...

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    menu = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self.imageView.image != nil) {
        menu.imageAdded = YES;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:menu.view];
}
```

MenuViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)albumButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"albumButtonPressed" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside my reservations about not applying proper view controller containment, the problem is that your `handleLongPress` will be called multiple times with different `recognizer.state` values, once as `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and again as `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. You should be checking the state of the gesture, e.g.:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        menu = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
        if (self.imageView.image != nil) {
            menu.imageAdded = YES;
        }
        [self.view addSubview:menu.view];
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer:**

I'd suggest putting a `NSLog` or breakpoint at your code with the `removeFromSuperview` and see if you're even getting to that piece of code.

There are some clear problems here. Specifically, you're not adding added the view associated `MenuViewController` in `handleLongPress` properly. If you want a subview with it's own controller, you have to use containment (and that only works with iOS 5 and later). And in containment, you have critical methods like [`addChildViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81), etc. See [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide* or see [WWDC 2011 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102). And, as an aside, you're also maintaining a strong reference to `MenuViewController`, so even if you succeeded in removing it's view, you'd leak the controller.

Spend a little time going through the containment documentation/video, and I think you'll want to revisit how you're presenting your menu. This is dense reading, but worth really understanding. Containment is powerful, but has to be done right.

Comment: Everything's OK when I call add a UIViewController as a subview in an IBAction method...but it's not working if I call in handLongPress method...

I'd like to use that interation for user

Comment: @o0oKodako0o Apple is pretty clear about the correct process for adding a subview that has its own controller, so I'll let you decide whether you want to follow Apple's guidance on that point or not. If not, though, I'm not sure we can help you too much. But, setting that aside, I'll ask my follow-up question again: If you put a `NSLog` or breakpoint in the `albumButtonPressed` in `MenuViewController`, is that method even getting called? I'd personally temporarily put log/breakpoints in all of the `MenuViewController` key methods, and confirm that they're all being called as you'd expect.

Comment: @o0oKodako0o Your gesture recognizer is not checking the `state`, and therefore is creating two view controllers and two views. Check `state` and you should be getting only one. That also explains the exception you're getting in your YouTube video. It also explains why it looks like it's not disappearing. It is, but your second one is still there.

Comment: By the way, if you put in those log statements I talked about earlier in all of the key `MenuViewController` methods, you probably would have seen that a bunch (like `viewDidLoad`) were getting called twice...

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

what do you mean by this?????? removing the main view!!!!

Comment: He's removing his popup, not the main menu. (We'll ignore the fact that `addSubview` and `removeFromSuperview` is not the best way to add a popup view controller and to remove it.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly using

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

use

```
 [[self.view.superview subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:self.view];
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in removing the menu view. The problem is that he has two of them because his gesture recognizer is creating two, so he's removing one, but not the other. He just need to tweak code so he only generates one menu as a result of the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @Rob I didn't work with UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Thank you for sharing this. +1 for that..:)